# Python Added Object to Dict

Tags: python, json, dictionary, collections

I have a JSON object that I want to add to an existing JSON Ojbect. When I add the object, it is added to bottom of the JSON, even though, the code added the new object first.

Here is an example of the JSON...

```
{
    "Header": {
        "ID": "Bob",
        "Description": "Description header_dict"
    },
    "Body": {
        "ItemInvolvesShortfall": {
            "SpecifiedBy": {
                "category": "Fibre To The Node",
                "version": "1.2.0",
                "type": "Shortfall Specification",
                "ID": "FTTN Shortfall"
            },
            "DescribedBy": {
                "Characteristic": {
                    "type": "Automatically fulfillable",
                    "ID": "pillar-patch"
                },
                "value": "Yes"
            }
        },
        "ID": "Bob",
        "Description": "Description body_dict"
    }
}
```

This is what I want the JSON to look like. ID and Description should be before ItemInvolvesShortfall.

```
….
"Body": {
        "ID": "Bob",
        "Description": "Description body_dict",
"ItemInvolvesShortfall": {
            "SpecifiedBy": {
                "category": "Fibre To The Node",
                "version": "1.2.0",
                "type": "Shortfall Specification",
                "ID": "FTTN Shortfall"
            },
            "DescribedBy": {
                "Characteristic": {
                    "type": "Automatically fulfillable",
                    "ID": "pillar-patch"
                },
                "value": "Yes"
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code snippet.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
import objectpath
import collections
#READ JSON OFF DISK
data = json.loads(open("/Users/AAAAAAAAAA/Documents/Python/Tuples/json/FTTN.json").read())
json_tree = objectpath.Tree(data['ManageTicketOfWorkRequest'])
#LOOK FOR A JSON OBJECT - ItemInvolvesShortfall
result = tuple(json_tree.execute('$..ItemInvolvesShortfall'))
new_dict=collections.OrderedDict()
header_dict={}
body_dict=collections.OrderedDict()

# CREATE HEADER   
header_dict["Header"]={
    "ID":"Bob",
    "Description":"Description header_dict" }

# CREATE BODY        
body_dict={"Body":{
    "ID":"Bob",
    "Description":"Description body_dict" }
    }

#ADD BODY INTO NEW DICTIONARY
new_dict.update(header_dict)
for i in result:

    #ADD THE ITEMINVOLVESSHORTFALL INTO BODY. THE ID & DESCRIPTION 
    #WHICH IS FIRST, NOT BE PUSH BACK. SHOULD I USE A POP OR POP_LEFT 
    #OR USE A APPEND OR APPEND_LEFT
    body_dict["Body"]["ItemInvolvesShortfall"]=i
    print('INFO:04 ', a)
    print(body_dict)

new_dict.update(body_dict)
print(" ", body_dict)
print("INFO05: ", body_dict)
new_dict.update(body_dict)
print("INFO06: ", new_dict)
```

Comment: Why do you do `body_dict=collections.OrderedDict()` and then replace that with a plain `dict` a few lines later? And at the end of your code, why do you do `new_dict.update(body_dict)` twice?

Comment: FWIW, there's not much point in using `OrderedDict` with JSON. A JSON Object (which is implemented in Python as a `dict`) is an _unordered_ collection of name-value pairs. So any software that processes JSON data _must not_ depend on those name-value pairs being in a specific order, and any tools that process JSON are not required to preserve order in Objects. Of course, if your JSON data is only read & written by software that you write, you can do what you like with it.

Comment: My thinking was new_dict will be the final dictionary that will be transformed to JSON. I will created the children JSON object in their own dictionaries and add them to new_dict. I thought the OrderedDict will preserver the sequence they were added. The sequence is import and the JSON need to conform to a specification provide by a client api.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries in Python (and most other languages) have no order to them - they are a **set** (unordered collection) of `key:value` pairs. Hence the argument that they are in the wrong order is incorrect as the premise that the data structure has an order is false.

Comment: I understand, maybe I should re-phrase my question, they json object needs to be in a certain sequence, it is not ordered by the key, but i need the ID first, then the description and finally the ItemInvolvesShortfall. There is specification that we need to conform towards and having the ItemInvolvesShortfall appear before the ID and Description will not comply with the specification.